# Is there a way to filter out all adjectives from a string and store them in an array?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
Apple Park is one of the most expensive and impressive buildings in the world. -> ["expensive","impressive"]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nltk
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

sentence = "Apple Park is one of the most expensive and impressive buildings in the world."
tags = nltk.pos_tag(sentence.split(' '))
adjectives = [w for w, t in tags if t == 'JJ']
print(adjectives)
```

prints:

```
['expensive', 'impressive']
```